# windows phone mango - differences between click and tap

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can anybody give me more details on this?

I know that tap is coming from gestures, but I'd like to know more on WP7 events model.

For instance how following scenarions work:

- stackpanel with tap event and checkbox inside which handles click
- container with tap and any framework element also with tap, etc.

Which events have more priority and if is it possible to mask events?

What kind of event bubbling is used here from top to bottom or vice-versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using WP7.1 SDK the easiest thing to make things consistent would be to use the Tap event everywhere (it's available on all UIElement derived controls). Tap events are bubbled up from the lowest control in the visual tree until a handler is found.

Then you don't need to worry about if/when Click and Tap will clash.

Comment: I agree this is the most reasonable way to go. However do you know if is there any good reference concerning event model in WP7 ?

Comment: It's the same as Silverlight - so this link should all be relevant http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189018(v=vs.95).aspx. I note that Tap isn't mentioned explicitly as Tap is a Windows Phone only method.